# ContextRefreshedEvent is invoking every time instead of ContextStartedEvent

Tags: java, spring, events

I am trying ApplicationListener but I get a `ContextRefreshedEvent` invoked every time. I want to know when `ContextStartedEvent` is invoked.

```
public class CustomListener implements ApplicationListener{

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent applicationEvent) {
       if(applicationEvent instanceof ContextRefreshedEvent){
           System.out.println("<><><>refresh event......");
       }else if(applicationEvent instanceof ContextStartedEvent){
            System.out.println("<><><><>started event......");
       }else{
           System.out.println("......else........");
       }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

ContextStartedEvent is published when you explicitly invoke ConfigurableAppicationContext.start() on the context

ContextRefreshedEvent may be published more than once, and therefore it may be also published before all the beans are initialized

**start()** is a method of Lifecycle interface which is extended by ConfigurableApplicationContext and explicitly implemented by org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.It is mainly used to support asynchronous processing

> Distinction between start and refresh is that:
>
> **refresh** is usually called implicitly during creation of concrete ApplicationContext, so we (developers) are more used to it.
>
> **start** is always explicit So - if you want to get ContextStartedEvent, you should call start() on ApplicationContext.

Answer (score 2):

This link may be helpful to you:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-events